# Tensorflow classifier.predict write to csv

Tags: pandas, tensorflow

I've not used Tensorflow for a while and when I updated it seemed to have broken my old code as many of the old functions are deprecated. I fixed them with the new code and it all seems to be running except for when I write out the results:

```
y_predicted = classifier.predict(X_test)
```

There is an as iterable option as well - which I don't think I need.

I use to write out the results of the predictions using:

```
pandas.DataFrame(y_predicted).to_csv(/dir/)
```

but now I am getting an error that not all elements can be converted into String type. Is there a class in y_predicted I am suppose to be calling instead of the whole thing?

Answer (score 0):

Anyways, I found a solution using np.array instead of a pandas dataframe:

```
result = np.asarray(y_predicted)
formatInt = result.astype(np.int)
np.savetxt("dir",formatInt,delimiter=",")
```

Comment: Then `pandas.DataFrame(np.asarray(y_predicted)).to_csv()` can works too.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try,

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({'Prediction':list(y_predicted)})
df.to_csv('filename.csv')
```